# integrable invarant after transitation

Tags: real-analysis

If $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, show
$$\int_\mathbb{R}f(x+t)dt=\int_\mathbb{R}f(t)dt$$
for $x\in(-\infty,+\infty)$.

**My thoughts**

Since 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-n-x}^{n-x}f(x+t)dt=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x+t)dt\;\;(\text{I am not sure if it is correct?})$$
then we change the variable by $t'=t+x$, we have
$$\int_{-n-x}^{n-x}f(x+t)dt=\int_{-n}^{n}f(t')dt'=\int_{-n}^{n}f(t)dt\rightarrow\int_\mathbb{R}f(t)dt,n\rightarrow\infty$$

Is this proof any problems?

maybe we can proof it by Simple function approximation theorem, and invariant of measure transition.